# Conditionally insert text node in XML document

Tags: php, xml, insert

The structure of my XML document is the following:

```
<tr>
<seg>
<source>source_text</source>
<dest>dest_text</dest>
</seg>

...
<seg>
<source>source_text</source>
</seg>

</tr>
```

Note that the dest element is not always present. I want to scan the file with PHP and insert a dest element (with some text) each time it's not present in a seg node.

Any help would be very appreciated.
Patrick

Comment: You'd better provide a real XML from your document, it would be much clearer what you mean

Comment: @Yaronius: It's just missing the code markup tag. Have made that edit but waiting for peer review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I tested this snippet, works for me:

```
$xml = '<tr>
<seg>
<source>source_text</source>
<dest>dest_text</dest>
</seg>
<seg>
<source>source_text</source>
</seg>
</tr>
';
$xmlObj = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach($xmlObj as $seg) {
    if(!$seg->dest) {
        $seg->dest = 'dest_text_inserted';
    }
}
echo $xmlObj->asXML();
```

It outputs what you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tr>
<seg>
<source>source_text</source>
<dest>dest_text</dest>
</seg>
<seg>
<source>source_text</source>
<dest>dest_text_inserted</dest></seg>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you Yaronius, works like a charm. I did't know about SimpleXMLElement. Thank you so much.